# Should we close old questions?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

Lately, I noticed several questions in the close review queue that were asked months or a year ago. We are currently going through a scoping process of close reasons, but should we be applying the new constraints and decisions on questions that were asked before the process began?

There was mention recently that we shouldn't go looking for questions to close due to the ongoing process, but newer users are likely to be looking at the older questions more than those of us who have been around a while and users who have recently gained the requisite permissions to close-vote may be overly enthusiastic to employ their new powers. Should we be encouraging, discouraging, or indifferent to such behaviors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We certainly shouldn't discourage it, if questions should be closed then closing them is a good idea.

Equally though I don't see a need to encourage it. If people see questions that need closing then we should close them but equally I don't think there is a need to specifically go hunting for questions to close.

Putting questions on hold is a mechanism to prevent people answering them while the question is improved. Old questions are already not being answered so closing them is redundant unless something somehow draws attention to them, at which point they can then be closed.

Comment: Am I correct in believing that an old, popular, off-topic can be closed in such a way that it doesn't auto-delete? Sort of a "historical interest" lock?

Comment: @nitsua60 Broadly speaking, questions that have upvoted answers do not get auto-deleted. You can read about the details at [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/157730) on [meta.se].